# Is capillary pressure significant?

Tags: hydraulics

I have a hydraulic system pressure to be measured in cm of water. It is done by tapping a graded tube, and simply measuring the height of the water column (usually at around 10-20 cm of water). If I tap down into that system using a 9 cm long 22-Gauge needle, is the capillary pressure significant enough to be added to that pressure, or can I just add that height as a normal water column? Thanks in advance.